# How to prevent 2 connection open in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, insert

I try something good code about prevent duplication of entries but I got error about connection. How can I fix this? Here's my code.

```
        if(label1.Text == "" || label2.Text == "" || label3.Text == "") {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Data");
        } else {
            String query = "Select * from Attendance where empIn=@empIn";
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("empIn", label2.Text);
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows) {
                MessageBox.Show("This Person has already IN");
            } else {
                insert();
            }            
        }
    }

    public void insert()
    {
        int i;
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Attendance (Name,Date,empIn)VALUES(@Name,@Date,@empIn)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(label1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empIn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label3.Text;
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i > 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
            label2.Text = "";
            label3.Text = "";
            label4.Text = "";

        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Deleted");
        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Some programmers solve this problem by implementing the database connection layer as singleton class or by using a ORM framework which connects to the database.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Is it because you have a `con.Open()` in both methods. Instead make `con` a class property and use the same one in all methods

Comment: Chetan Ranpariya System.InvalidOperationException: 'Connection must be valid and open.' but when i Open on top of query he says Connection has already Open

Comment: @RiggsFolly so the query select too i will make methods ?

Comment: Well I assume the code at the top of your question is part of another Method. It would be useful to see that in your question if that is the case

Comment: @Strudops One solution would be to create a new connection inside of `insert` and remove the global connection object. With connection pooling enabled creating new connections for each call should be no problem.

Comment: Net uses a connection pool.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the  "using" state which will create and close the connection automatically

```
public object getQueryScaller(string sqlQuery)
    {
        object value = null;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

This will Automatically control the connection problem you will have no need to take care of it. just passing the parameter into the function as SQL statement and it will work.